# Resource reservation system

Tags: performance, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I'm using a function to determine if resources can be used again or not.
This is the numpy array I'm using.

```
 'Resource_id', 'Start_date', 'end_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'overload'
   [548, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',2],
   [546, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',2],
   [546, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',2],
   [543, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-16', '08:45:00', '17:40:00',1],
```

1. First step is to find all resource available on a date, for example (2019-05-16 from 8:30 to 17:30). To achieve this I used `np.where` like the example below:

   ```
    av_resource_np = resource_availability_np[np.where(
    (resource_availability_np[:,1] <= '2019-05-16')
    & (resource_availability_np[:,2] >= '2019-05-16')
    & (resource_availability_np[:,3] <= '17:30:00') 
    & (resource_availability_np[:,4] >= '08:30:00'))]
   ```
2. Here I try to find unique resource ids and the sum of their overload factor using `np.unique()`:

   ```
    unique_id, count_nb = np.unique(av_resource_np[:,(0,5)], axis=0, return_counts=True)
    availability_mat = np.column_stack((unique_id, count_nb ))
   ```

Which yields the following results:

```
'Resource_id' 'overload' 'Count'
548           2           1
546           2           2
543           1           1
```

3. A simple filtering is done to select which resource hat can't be used in this date. If a resource is used in the same date `more or equal (>=)` to its`overload`, then we can't use it again.

   ```
     rejected_resources = availability_mat [np.where(availability_mat [:, 2] >= availability_mat [:, 1])]
   ```

**Result** here should be both resource `543` and `546` which can't be used again.

So this is main idea behind my function, the problem here is that it takes more than 60% of the whole program runtime and I would appreciate any advice about how to make it more efficient/faster. Thank you.

Full code:

```
def get_available_rooms_on_date_x(date, start_time, end_time, resource_availability_np):

    av_resource_np = resource_availability_np[np.where(
    (resource_availability_np[:,1] <= date)
    & (resource_availability_np[:,2] >= date)
    & (resource_availability_np[:,3] <= end_time) 
    & (resource_availability_np[:,4] >= start_time))]

    unique_id, count_nb = np.unique(av_resource_np[:,(0,5)], axis=0, return_counts=True)

    availability_mat = np.column_stack((unique_id, count_nb ))
    
    rejected_resources = availability_mat [np.where(availability_mat [:, 2] >= availability_mat [:, 1])]
    
    return rejected_resources
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. This question could be improved if you change the title to something like `Room Reservation System` and include the entire program. You state that the function takes 60% of the program execution time, it would help us optimize the code if we could see the rest of the program. The title should be about what the code does, and not what your concerns are about the code. Actual questions about the code should be in the body of the post. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: I see you tagged this with pandas, but didn't mention it in your question or use it in your example code. Are you considering using a pandas dataframe instead of your array?

Comment: Also, is your numpy array a record array for an ndarray with an object dtype?

Comment: @PaulH, i was using this with pandas but it gave me worse performance so i tried it with numpy. Also ndarray has the correct type for each column.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Could you add code that generates the ndarray?

Comment: The resource_availability_np array receives data from a converted pandas dataframe to numpy while removing unnecessary columns. I have changed the type of ndarray also so its no longer objects,  this made it slightly faster unfortuanly not what i look for.